# 400 Bad Request error on Delete

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, request, http-delete

Me and my m8s are developing a manuscript handling system for our university using Spring MVC,angularJS etc. We have some issues with deleting a user from the database.

We get always HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'userName' is not present

type Status report

message Required String parameter 'userName' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Controller:

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteUser(@RequestParam String userName) {
    LOGGER.info("Deleted user: " + userName);
    userManagerService.deleteUser(userName);
}
```

Method of the ManuscriptAdminService.js:

```
function deleteUser(userName){
    $log.info("Delete selected user "+new Date());
    $http.delete('delete/'+userName).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },function(error){
        $log.error("Error occured while admin tried to delete user "+new Date());
    });
}
```

Method of the ManuscriptAdminController.js

```
    vm.showModalUserDelete = function(index) {
    $log.info("Show user delete modal "+new Date());
    var modelInstance = $modal
            .open({
                animation : true,
                templateUrl : 'htmlcontent/content/admin/modal/userDeleteManageModal.html',
                controller : 'ManuscriptAdminModalinstacneController',
                controllerAs : 'ManuscriptAdminModalinstacneController',
                size : 300,
                resolve : {
                    items : function() {
                        return ManuscriptAdminService.getUserName(index);
                    }

                }
            });

    modelInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        ManuscriptAdminService.deleteUser(result);
        }, function () {
          $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a URI template variable in `/delete/{userName}`, so you will need to use `@PathVariable` annotation on your parameter:

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteUser(@PathVariable String userName) {
    LOGGER.info("Deleted user: " + userName);
    userManagerService.deleteUser(userName);
}
```